# Handle session expire in MVC 2 with ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, session-timeout

I want to check  the  session expired or not. 
SO what i decided is  Create an action called IsServerExpired and have it return a json object containing a boolean value, and the redirect url.

SO the java script function  will do an ajax request to this action with specified time interval ..
I have some basic questions ..

1.If i send an ajax request ,i think that will refresh the session time . So in effect the session will not expire if i am using this method.  am i right ?

If it refreshes how can i  check session expire using polling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more simple approach to log out user once session expired.

You can save `SessionTimeout` somewhere on the client side and run client side timer, once timer reach end redirect user to log out url.

Here is example. `Model` here containts `SessionTimeout` value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var timeOutInMinutes = @Model;
  if(timeOutInMinutes > 0)
  {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location = 
              '@Url.Action("Logout", "Authentication", new {area=""})';   
    },timeOutInMinutes * 1000 * 60);
  }
});
```

More user friendly way is to show popup that will say that session will be expired wihtin one minute(if session timeout 15 mins then show it after 14 mins), so user will be able refresh page. and continue work.

Comment: If  I am doing ajax calls after the page load, this method won't consider that. Isn't it? That is a shortcoming for my scenario.

Comment: Yes, this method just wait on client side according to Session Timeout  value in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing between an ASP.NET session and the authentication cookie. I suspect that you are talking about the authentication cookie expiration here. If you have set `slidingExpiration` to true in your web.config then polling AJAX requests will renew the timeout so they are not suitable. Phil Haack described a very elegant way to detect authentication cookie expiration in AJAX calls in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx).